# When I using the storyboard, the function of applicationWillResignActive can't be recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't know why.But when I using xib, there is no problem.

error messages like this:

```
2014-04-17 16:59:11.413 State Lab[2227:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8d800c0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)

2014-04-17 16:59:11.453 State Lab[2227:60b] application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

2014-04-17 16:59:11.459 State Lab[2227:60b] applicationDidBecomeActive:

2014-04-17 16:59:11.461 State Lab[2227:60b] -[spsViewController applicationDidBecomeActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f8f390
2014-04-17 16:59:11.463 State Lab[2227:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[spsViewController applicationDidBecomeActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f8f390'
```

*** First throw call stack:

my code:

```
   #import "spsViewController.h"

    @interface spsViewController ()

    @property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL animate;

    - (void)rotateLabelUp;
    - (void)rotateLabelDown;

    @end

    @implementation spsViewController

    @synthesize label, animate;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
        CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, CGRectGetMidY(bounds) - 50, bounds.size.width, 100);
        self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:70];
        label.text = @"Bazinga!";
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        [self rotateLabelDown];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        self.label = nil;
    }

    - (void)rotateLabelDown
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5
                         animations:^{
                             label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [self rotateLabelUp];
                         }];
    }

    - (void)rotateLabelUp
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5
                         animations:^{
                             label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             if (animate)
                                 [self rotateLabelDown];
                         }];
    }

    - (void)applicationWillResignActive
    {
        NSLog(@"VC: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        animate = NO;
    }

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
    {
        NSLog(@"VC: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        animate = YES;
        [self rotateLabelDown];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Your method has no parameters... And you said it had one when you set the notification (you put ":").

Answer (score 1):

Change your , @selector(**applicationDidBecomeActive:**) to  @selector(**applicationDidBecomeActive**)

Since your method signature is   `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive`